# How to get the selectionchange event in PyQt4 for QListView

Tags: pyqt4, qlistview

Hi have a QListView created using QtDesigner and converted to python using pyuic4, and I imported the UI module where I am trying to connect it to events

for the QlistView i am trying to implement selection change when user presses up and down key, I am guessing the event should be fired when selection changes but that doesn't seems to do something

```
self.methodListView.selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.outputHelp)
```

but this gives error

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'selectionChanged'
```

Do I need to add some more information to show exactly what I am doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self.methodListView.selectionModel` isn't an attribute, it's a function which returns the selection model. Just use

```
self.methodListView.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.outputHelp)
```

and it should work...

Comment: no,      self.methodListView.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.outputHelp)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectionChanged'

Comment: That means `self.methodListView.selectionModel()` returns `None` - which means you probably didn't set the model. You need to set the model before you can connect to it's selectionChanged signal.

Comment: Yes I realized that, I had all the signal handler defined in a _connections method, so instead of keeping it there, I moved this one to where the list gets populated and model is available.